# What is the best practice to handle errors in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I have some knowledge about handling errors in Express but I wanted to know if I really am on the right track. A simple example:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Middleware 1 called.")
  console.log(req.path)
  next() // calling next middleware function or handler
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log("Route handler called.")
  res.send("Hello world!") // response sent back – no more middleware called
})

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Last middleware called?") // not called
})
```

Here last middleware is not called, maybe because the response is returned in each route, so what would be an optimal way to handle errors in Express?

How to implement middleware that catches error, whenever my app crashes I want to notify myself, that's why I want to use a middleware that runs right after an error happens.

What I do right now is use `try` and `catch` on every route where an error is expected and there I notify myself by sending a mail or something.

Comment: Is your question about this specific fragment of code - or about middleware usage in general?

Comment: _What_ errors? Have you read e.g. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html?

Comment: Again I'd recommend reading Express's docs on middleware - especially the _error-handling_ kind.

Comment: man i have tried at this point i have some question if someone can answer my questions i might get what i need

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using try and catch for every single route, prefer to use a default error middle-ware in express, a minimal example to demonstrate a complete flow of basic or mandatory middle-wares is following but read [this](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) doc for more details.

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors()); //first define cors
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); //then body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json()); //the encoding of data

app.use(
  session()//your session settings if you want
);

app.use('/assets', express.static('public/uploads')); //your static assets
app.use('/api', routes); //your actual routes, do not use try catch, express will handle its own

app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(apiSpec)); //swagger route

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {  
    return res.status(500).json({
      status: 'error',
      message: err.message,
      path: req.path
    });
}); //default error handler, magic happens here
```

You can even define your own error types e.g. check following code which exports three different types of error to throw

```
class GeneralError extends Error {
  code = 200;

  constructor(message, code) {
    super();
    this.message = message;
    this.code = code;
  }

  getCode() {
    if (this instanceof BadRequest) {
      if (this.code) {
        return this.code;
      }
      return 400;
    }
    if (this instanceof NotFound) {
      return 404;
    }
    return 500;
  }
}

class BadRequest extends GeneralError {}
class NotFound extends GeneralError {}

module.exports = {
  GeneralError,
  BadRequest,
  NotFound,
};
```

Comment: just a quick question, on every route there's only res.send() so that means no next() is used or what so ever which means the chain does not continue so this middleware that you used will not work right ?

Comment: No basically error middleware can be called explicitly by calling next if you know the exception but for uncaught exceptions express will automatically call the error middleware, no need of next here. use next only if you want to throw custom error e.g. next(customError);